# Call view inside another view with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to call view inside another view with some parameters added.

My parameters are:

```
string cFNM;
string cLNM;
integer iUSER_ID;
```

I've found out how to call view, but I don't know how to pass parameters to that view call?

```
  <div id="divProductsTable">
     @{ Html.RenderAction("SearchProducts", "Operation"); }
  </div>
```

Comment: `@{ Html.RenderAction("SearchProducts", "Operation", new { cFNM = someValue, cLNM = someValue, etc }); }`

Comment: Interesting, they are not calling this parameters but route values. Can you post this as answer, please.

Comment: You may have some terminology mixed up. `RenderAction()` is actually calling an method in your controller (which may return view) and its referred to as `routeValues` because the expectation is you have a route defined for it, and if you don't then they will be query string parameters (and an answer as now been added by Chetan Ranpariya - although its not a `RouteValueDictionary` - its an `object` in that example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third parameter of `Html.RenderAction` accepts objects of RouteValueDictionary containing the parameters to be passed to the controller action.

You can use it as following.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("SearchProducts", "Operation", 
    new {param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2" }); }
```